# Getting Exception in Jedis

Tags: redis, jedis

I am getting the following exceptions while accessing Jedis sometimes.

Exception 1:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [B
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryBulkReply(Connection.java:204)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBulkReply(Connection.java:193)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.get(Jedis.java:89)
```

Exception 2:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Protocol error: invalid bulk length
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:113)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:131)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:200)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:285)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryBulkReply(Connection.java:204)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBulkReply(Connection.java:193)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.get(Jedis.java:89)
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: What is the code that produced these errors?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a Jedis bug. Redis has limitation of various bulk length, and it is not documented well. Look at [this question](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1034) for example. And look at multibulk length limitation [in Redis source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/networking.c#L1043-1118):

> If you total response more than 512*1024*1024 bytes your will catch `invalid bulk length` error (line 1118).

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure class files "implements Serializable" .

Example:

```
public class Sample1 extends Sample2 implements Serializable
{
  // implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call Jedis.close() method after you do operation with Jedis instance.